# Editing WebSphere variables - from wsadmin

Tags: websphere

There are "enviornment > WebSphere variables". I read I can set one if I wanted, using AdminControl.setVariable and so on.

But what if I want to delete a certain veriable, from all possible scopes? I looked over the internet and found nothing substential on this.

The following thing can help me:
**A way to go over all of the scopes (clusters, servers, nodes):
Then I can go over them, look for the variable and delete it. Any way of listing all servers, nodes and clusters?**

Thank.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the InfoCenter article on [Modifying variables using wsadmin scripting](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/txml_variable.html) and [Commands for the AdminConfig object using wsadmin scripting](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_adminconfig1.html), you want to do something like this:

```
ls = java.lang.System.getProperty("line.separator");

# List all config objects in the cell by not passing a parent config object.
varSubsts = AdminConfig.list("VariableSubstitutionEntry").split(ls)

for varSubst in varSubsts
  varName = AdminConfig.showAttribute(varSubst, "symbolicName")
  if varName == "MyVarToDelete":
    AdminConfig.remove(varSubst)
```